# pandas value_counts include all values before groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1, -1], ['a', 1, -1], ['b', 0, -1], ['c', -1, -1]] ,columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df
    col1    col2    col3
0   a       1       -1
1   a       1       -1
2   b       0       -1
3   c       -1      -1
```

Now I want to groupby the df by the columns, and for each one, count the number of appearances of the values in the columns `col1` separately.

```
groupby_df = df.groupby('col1') 
for a,b in groupby_df:
    print("{0} -> \n{1}".format(a, b['col1'].value_counts().sort_index()))
```

I get:

```
a -> 
a    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64
b -> 
b    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
c -> 
c    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

But I want to count the number of appearances **separately** , and still include all the column values, as follows:

```
a -> 
a    2
b    0
c    0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
b -> 
a    0
b    1
c    0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
c -> 
a    0
b    0
c    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you try expanding on the purpose of doing this? Does the exact output formatting matter? Why not just use `df.col1.value_counts()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [.reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a',1, -1], ['a', 1, -1], ['b', 0, -1], ['c', -1, -1]] ,columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

# Create index using unique values of col1.

uniques = pd.Index(df['col1'].unique())

# Group.

groupby_df = df.groupby('col1')

# Use reindex to assign and autoamtically align the value counts with the index.

for a, b in groupby_df:
    print(b['col1'].value_counts().sort_index().reindex(uniques, fill_value = 0))
```

Gives:

```
a    2
b    0
c    0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
a    0
b    1
c    0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
a    0
b    0
c    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```