# All possibilities with groupby and value_counts(), issue with Multindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ACCOUNT_ID | OPTION 
1              A      
2              A        
2              B
2              B
2              C
```

I want to count the groups for each so I ran `df.groupby(['ACCOUNT_ID'])['OPTION'].value_counts()` and the result looks like this:

```
ACCOUNT_ID | OPTION 
1              A         1
2              A         1
2              B         2
2              C         1
```

This works well but I want every possible option to be shown (so A, B, C counts for each account_id) like:

```
ACCOUNT_ID | OPTION 
1              A         1
1              B         0
1              C         0
2              A         1
2              B         2
2              C         1
```

I found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516126/pandas-value-counts-include-all-values-before-groupby), using `.sort_index().reindex(uniques, fill_value = 0)`, which looks great, but doesn't work since I am using a MultiIndex.

Any tips would be amazing!!

Comment: Are `A, B, C` the only values in `OPTION` column?

Comment: Yes they are, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to `unstack` the inner level of the MultiIndex into columns. This gives you a DataFrame whose columns have `float64` dtype, with `NaN` values for missing combinations of `ACCOUNT_ID` and `OPTION`. Fill NaNs with 0, convert back to integer dtype with `astype`, and `stack` the columns back into the index to recreate the MultiIndex:

```
df.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int).stack()

ACCOUNT_ID  OPTION
1           A         1
            B         0
            C         0
2           A         1
            B         2
            C         1
dtype: int64
```